# Web app refuses to be in a normal tab, how to force it?

Tags: google-chrome

When I log into my online banking, it insists on opening as a separate window.

[image]

I get no tabs, no icons for extensions, no reload or back buttons, nothing.

I've tried to make it open as a normal tab. I've tried to merge it with a normal Chrome window.

I think it's annoying that I can't have it as a tab, especially in terms of multitasking, etc.

How can I force this web app to be in a tab?

I use Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit) on OS X 10.10.1.

Comment: This looks intentional to prevent users from accidentally clicking back or reload which could interfere with certain transactions. I am not entirely sure why this was migrated from WebApps. It seems a better fit there...

Comment: See this page: http://javascript.info/tutorial/popup-windows

Comment: You could try to cut and paste the URL into a regular tab in your browser. That worked in the past when ING internet banking did the same.

Comment: @Burgi Yes,  it could be to prevent people from pressing those buttons. I still want it in a normal tab,  though. I don't know why it was moved from Web Apps.  Maybe because the solution will likely involve the browser or the OS,  and not anything within the web app itself? Just a wild guess.

Comment: @Hennes What URL? The way I normally get the net banking to open is to enter my login details and click `LOGIN` and that's when the pop-up window comes. After logging in, I've tried pasting the url from the pop-up window (`https://www.kvbin.com/B001/internet`) into a new tab, but that simply gives a white page with the text `ERROR PAGE` in big, black letters.

Comment: Can you screenshot the context menu when you right-click the title bar?

Comment: @Frankie By "title bar", you mean the bar at the very top of the window, where it says `KVB Net-Banking`? Right clicking that gives nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can put it in a tab.  I'm guessing that the new window is created by the bank application using some javascript/js library.  When the bank application has created the new window the options that make up the window (resize, close window, etc ) are turned off in order to control it.

Comment: Alright. Resizing, though, works.

Comment: They may have left that on.  Here's an example of how someone can control what features are on and off when creating a browser window in javascript.  window.open(url,'PopupWindow','left=50, top=50, height=200, width=500,       toolbars=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=0,status=yes');

Comment: Interesting. Couldn't it be possible to have an extension or something to override that? For example, some sites try to disable right clicks, copy, paste, etc., avd i have extensions to override all that.

Comment: Not that I know of.  I am aware of the cut/copy/paste override.  That is typically just javascript capturing the event and calling preventDefault() in order to prevent anything from happening.  In this case, the window is already created.  I haven't heard of a way of changing the attributes of a window that is already created.

Comment: Alright, I see :)